# Call native python interpreter instead of anaconda

Tags: python, python3, anaconda

I installed anaconda3 on Ubuntu. Everything is running flawlessly except for one small issue. When using the command "python" to run some arbitrary python file, it runs python3 using anaconda instead of the native 2.7 python interpreter. How can I change that? 
In other words : 
what is happening right now:

```
python ex.py
```

ex.py is run by anaconda3

```
python2.7 ex.py
```

ex.py is run by python2.7

```
python3 ex.py
```

ex.py is run by anaconda3

what I want to happen:

```
python ex.py
```

ex.py is run by python2.7

```
python2.7 ex.py
```

ex.py is run by python2.7

```
python3 ex.py
```

ex.py is run by anaconda3

Comment: Whats the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: /home/john/anaconda3/bin:/home/john/.local/share/umake/bin:/home/john/bin:/home/john/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: Ok I solved it by renaming the file name "python" inside anaconda3/bin

Comment: why would you do that? Please check my answer...

Answer (score 0):

As seen from the output of `echo $PATH`:

```
/home/john/anaconda3/bin:/home/john/.local/share/umake/bin:/‌​home/john/bin:/home/‌​john/.local/bin:/usr‌​/local/sbin:/usr/loc‌​al/bin:/usr/sbin:/us‌​r/bin:/sbin:/bin:/us‌​r/games:/usr/local/g‌​ames:/snap/bin
```

The `/home/john/anaconda3/bin` directory comes first and as the relevant `python`(analogous to `python2`) and `python3` binaries are present in the directory, all your `python` scripts are being interpreted by binaries in that directory, not the system-wide ones that come with `python-minimal` (`python2`) and `python3-minimal` (`python3`) packages, and present in `/usr/bin` directory that comes later in your `PATH`.

You need to:

- either use the full path to the systems' ones

Or

- drop the `/home/john/anaconda3/bin` directory from the `PATH`, append the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

  ```
  export PATH='/home/john/.local/share/umake/bin:/‌​home/john/bin:/home/‌​john/.local/bin:/usr‌​/local/sbin:/usr/loc‌​al/bin:/usr/sbin:/us‌​r/bin:/sbin:/bin:/us‌​r/games:/usr/local/g‌​ames:/snap/bin'
  ```

  You can do:

  ```
  echo "export PATH='<above_path_here>'" >>~/.bashrc
  ```

  Not sure if you want to keep `/home/john/.local/share/umake/bin, make your choice.

---

Just for the sake of completeness, both `python2` and `python3` are actually symlinked to the respective latest binaries present on the system.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to deactivate conda environment.
The best advice is activate your conda environment only when you need (remove `conda activate` from your `.bashrc` file) and thus, python system will be use in the common tasks of your OS without issues or unexpected behaviors.